# When I add html to my template Mustache stops displaying data. any Ideas on how to fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, mustache

This is my template, as soon as i remove the html tags it works, but i need the html tags for styling.

```
<p>{{username}}</p>
```

And this is how I load/display my template

```
       $.get('app/templates/login.htm', function(template) {
            var templateData = {
                username: "eelke"
            };
            $('#container').append(Mustache.render(template, templateData));
            alert('Load was performed.');
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `dataType: 'html'` to your options on the ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'app/templates/login.htm',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(template) {
        var templateData = {
            username: "eelke"
        };
        $('#container').append(Mustache.render(template, templateData));
        alert('Load was performed.');
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanx i thought with jquery get that would happen automatically.  This Works so thanx a lot.